# what is the way to access value of prors in react native Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props

I want to access get props of a clicked Component to get the value of the prop with name number in the Marker component when I press on the component

I have used an array to push my components in

```
markers = []
this.markers.push(<Marker 
                  onPress={()=> this._shapeFocused(event) }  
                  coordinate={latLng} data={this.state.markerNumber} 
                  key={"MN-" + this.state.markerNumber}
                  number={"5"}
                  //value={"marker"}
              ></Marker>)
```

after the components are pushed. on pressing one of them I want to get the value of its prop "number" to send it to the global store **I have tried event.props.prop but it doesn't work**

```
  _shapeFocused(e) {
    //get the key of the component
   let key = e.target.number;
    // send the component key to the global state:
   let action = { type: "ShapeFocused", value: key}
   this.props.dispatch(action)
  }
```

i will really aprecate if you can tell the way i cann acess the value of props in react native.
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event` is a React synthetic event that knows nothing about your Marker or its props. In this case, it seems you're not really interested in the event details, only when it's triggered.

What you probably want instead is just dispatch the action with the value of the current Marker.

```js
<Marker 
  onPress={() => shapeFocused(this.state.markerNumber)}
  coordinate={latLng}
  data={this.state.markerNumber} 
  key={"MN-" + this.state.markerNumber}
/>

function shapeFocused(markerNumber) {
  const action = { type: "ShapeFocused", value: markerNumber }
  this.props.dispatch(action)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in that way it will get the same state value of each clicked component. The point is i want to assign to every new component "Marker" a value of "state + 1"  incrementally. And when i click on certain Marker component get it's proper value .

Comment: You can pass whatever argument to `shapeFocused`. I just used `this.state.markerNumber` as an example but you can do something like `markers.map(index => <Marker onPress={() => shapeFocused(index)} ... />)`. That way each marker will trigger `shapeFocused` with a different argument.

Comment: thank u man. that's what I was looking for, thank's a lot. I really appreciated it